# How should I continue my running training for fat loss

Tags: running, weight-loss, bellyfat

I am 5'8", weigh about 155 lbs. I look rather fit except for my bulky belly.

For the past month or so, I have been running on the Planet Fitness treadmill. This week, I managed to run for 30 minutes (12 mins + 10 mins + 8 mins, with 4 mins and 6 mins break in between). My pace was 10 mins 21 seconds for a mile (5.8 on Planet Fitness treadmill). Also, I didn't use any inclination.

How should I continue from here:

1. Should I increase the duration of the sets? To maybe 15 mins, 12 mins, 10 mins?
2. Should I try to add another set of 8 mins?
3. Should I try to decrease the break time between the sets?
4. Should I try to increase the inclination a bit?
5. Should I try to increase my pace, so that I do one mile under 10 mins?

BTW, I also do some light dumbbell exercises for ~15 mins after running.

Comment: Are you only interested in making changes to your running (what about weight training)? When you say "This week, I managed to run for 30 minutes", does that mean you only ran 30 minutes for the whole week?

Comment: Are you trying to loose weight or get good at running or improve your body composition? They're all valid goals but don't really require the same sorts of training.

Answer (score 1):

Okay You got basically two options when it comes to elevating energy expenditure associated with fat loss.

There are two factors included in training load at the basic level of the model:

- Volume (time)
- Intensity (speed, duration of the breaks between the sets, inclination)

You can work further based on increasing one or the other (or both at the same time), but keep in mind that the easiest way would be to increase volume.

Trying to increase intensity is a whole lot different because then you need to be aware of the anaerobic threshold.

If you want to be more explosive and sprint I would go for raising the intensity slowly. You can do that by modifying the aspects stated above.

If you want to go towards more endurance, then I would try to work on the edge of anaerobic threshold and try to get more volume in my training.